# Beego Templates - Use persistent template with static pages

Tags: templates, persistent, beego

I am using Beego and I was able to get a persistent template to work on the index.tpl page (which has a website banner, menu navigation, footer, etc) However, when I click off the index page and go to one of my static pages i.e "contact" page. The persistent template doesn't appear. How can I add a persistent template to all my static pages under /static/pages directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use layout concepts.

for homepage controller;

```
this.Layout = "layout.html"
this.TplNames = "index.html"
```

for contact page controller;

```
this.Layout = "layout.html"
this.TplNames = "contact.html"
```

layout.html

```
{{template "header.html"}}
{{template "banner.html"}}
{{.LayoutContent}}
{{template "footer.html"}}
```

LayoutContent variable refers controllers TplNames file.

https://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md